# Spinner losing focus after item is selected

Tags: android

I have a dialog with a bunch of EditTexts and Spinners. They are all inside a ScrollView and the dialog can sometimes be large enough for the scroll bar to be required.

When I select an item from a spinner, it will lose focus and switch to the first EditText in the dialog. When they are all shown on the screen, this is not a big problem, but when the spinner is on the bottom, it will auto scroll to the top to select the first EditText. And that's where it becomes very annoying.

I have tried calling requestFocus() on the spinner inside it's itemSelectedListener but it did not work. I had the same problem with buttons. When they were clicked, the focus would be switched to the first EditText, but requesting focus inside the button's click listener solved it.

EDIT:
I have noticed that the spinners were not focusable. After setting setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode to true, the first EditText would no longer get selected, but the viewpoint would still be scrolled to it. How do I prevent this?

Comment: i also stuck at same problem. Is you found any solution?

Comment: @MitulVarmora I did, but I don't remember how. :(